# C# Eval not displaying value within Div tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, itemtemplate

I am using an eval statement to display a string from a column value.  Everything is setup fine in that regard, but when I put it into a bit of HTML, my text vanishes.  Any ideas?

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle offense-icon added-hours" id="Offense_1" <%# Eval("OFFENSE").ToString() == "" ? "hidden" : "" %>></i>
    <div id="addedDescription1" class="added-hours-description hide-description">
        <%# Eval("OFFENSE") %>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Browser HTML:

```
<td>
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle offense-icon added-hours" id="Offense_1" ></i>
    <div id="addedDescription1" class="added-hours-description hide-description">
        Missing Document
    </div>
</td>
```

Hide description CSS:

```
.hide-description {
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact rendered html for this template when you check your browser's View Source?

Comment: What does the `hide-description` CSS do?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Added the browser side html to the OP.

Comment: @RonBeyer Added the CSS to OP.  Wasn't done by me but plain text displays in there fine.

Comment: What's the point of using a css class containing `visibility: hidden` and expecting it to be displayed? Is this proposital or you didn't realize what the css was doing?

Comment: I have a bit of JS to toggle the class on click so it acts like a pop up.  Works as intended with plain text but not an Eval statement.

Comment: To be clear, is the HTML in the "Browser HTML" section of your question the actual, rendered HTML that your browser sees?  If so, I don't see how the `Eval` is even relevant.

Comment: The `id` attribute on your `div` won't be unique unless your template is rendered only once.  That's invalid HTML.

Comment: @ConnorMackay, Eval is running at server side, not in your browser. As long it returns a text the browser would handle it as any other content.

Comment: I can put an Eval Statement and a plaintext word in the itemtemplate for this div.  When I click the icon, the plaintext work appears, but not the Eval statement restult.

Comment: When I put in the Eval without the hidden div, it returns what im expecting / :

Comment: I don't believe your issue is related to the `Eval()` at all.

Answer (score 0):

The text is there. You need to remove the `hide-description` css class from the `div` to be able to see it.

Comment: Its hidden and I have a bit of JS to toggle the class when the icon is clicked.  I want it to be hidden until it is clicked and this works fine with plain text but not the Eval statement.